# C=C++; why the value is not changing of C variable as it remain 0

Tags: c, assignment-operator, post-increment

Why the value of C is not changing when i use `c=c++;` instruction.

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int t, c=0,d;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n>=50)
    {
        c=c++;
        printf("%d\n",c);
    }
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Input
4
50
8
25
78
Output
0
0
0

Comment: `c=c++;` -> `c++;`.

Comment: `c=c++` means first `c=c` then `c+1` that not change value of `c`, you can use either `c++` or `c=c+1`.

Answer (score 5):

```
c=c++;
```

This keeps on resetting the value of `c`.

Either do:

```
c++;
```

or:

```
c+= 1;
```

Dont do both increment and assignment.